# How do you write a new text file (and also an excel file) to your default directory or a specific directory using python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I used the code below from *Starting Out WIth Python 5th edition* and I do not see a text file in the directory I specified. I used Jupyter notebook to run the code:

```
def main():
       # Open a file named philosophers.txt.
       outfile = open(r'C:\Users\ME\philosophers.txt', 'w')
 
       # Write the names of three philosphers
       # to the file.
       outfile.write('John Locke\n')
       outfile.write('David Hume\n')
       outfile.write('Edmund Burke\n')

       # Close the file.
       outfile.close()

  # Call the main function.
if __name__ == '_ _main_ _':
          main()
```

I ran the code included in this post and all I see is a file called IPNYB in the directory. I suppose it is a Jupyter notebook file. I was expecting a plain old text file named philosophers.txt. Then I went into the directory I chose, created a text filed, named it "philosophers.txt" then I ran the python code and the text file was till empty and did not include the text I specified in the outfile.write methods.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!
You should use os module to avoid trouble in cross-platform and do this:

```
import os
filename = "philosophers.txt"

x = os.path.join("C:/Users/ME", "filename")

with open(x, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("John Locke\n")
    outfile.write("David Hume\n")
    outfile.write("Edmund Burke\n")
    outfile.close
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, However I receive No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/ME/filename' Shouldn't python create the file philosophers.txt if it does not exist in the directory?